# How to get html input into php sql

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get the values where a person searches a staff ID from that input from the html page  it will show all processed purchases from that Staff ID

```
$name = $_GET["staffID"];
$sql = "SELECT orderID, orderDate, shippingDate, staffName FROM purchase
WHERE staffID = ".$name." 
INNER JOIN staff ON purchase.staffID =
staff.staffID ORDER BY orderDate";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error());
```

The errors im getting are apparent when I put the WHERE statement in, So i don't know if im doing the WHERE statement correctly or not.

Without the where statement it will show me all purchases from all staff ids in the table which is right

```
<html> 
</head>
<body>

<form id="staff" action="file.php" method="get">
<p>please fill in the following form</p>
<p>Staff ID:  <input type="text" name="staffID"/>
</p>

<p><input type="submit"  value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tr reordering `WHERE` & `INNER JOIN` clauses;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 getting an error Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in I:*Path* on line 23 Problem with query....... line 23 being the last line in that code "or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error());"

Comment: `or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($conn));` means pass `$conn` variable to `mysqli_error()`; then share the error;

Comment: Can you please post the HTML form?

Comment: @TheCodesee will post now

Comment: You should use prepared statement to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not put delimiters around the name variable:

```
$sql = "SELECT orderID, orderDate, shippingDate, staffName FROM purchase
INNER JOIN staff ON purchase.staffID =
staff.staffID ORDER BY orderDate
WHERE staffID = '".$name."' ";
```

Comment: I have updated my answer - please try the query with the WHERE clause reordered, as per itzmukeshy7 suggestion

Comment: Still getting the same error, Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in I:"Path" on line 24 Problem with query which is the or die(... line

Comment: You need to pass your connection into the mysqli_error function like this mysqli_error($conn);

Comment: With this code [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) is possible right @MarcStevenPlotz?

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
$name = isset($_GET['staffID'])?$_GET['staffID']:'';
if(!empty($name) && $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT orderID, orderDate, shippingDate, staffName FROM purchase INNER JOIN staff ON purchase.staffID = staff.staffID WHERE staffID = ? ORDER BY orderDate')){
  /**
   * Here 1st parameter is data type of field s for string and i for integer;
   * @todo update "s" as per data type of staffID field;
   */
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

  /* execute query */
  $stmt->execute();

  /* Get result: */
  $result = $stmt->get_result();

  /* now you can fetch the results into an array - NICE */
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    /**
     * @todo use $row as per your requirement;
     */
  }

  /* close statement */
  $stmt->close();
}

/* optional close connection */
$conn->close();
```

**Preventing SQL injection too;** and also check for blank value of `$_GET['staffID']`;